# Excel Formula Compare Data

Tags: excel

I have a problem where I need to compare cells in a large list and find the following question below...

Question: How many times was a 0 value found before a 1 value in the list?
This list is vertical(FYI) and also I will be unable to use macros, just need assistance in creating an IF formula for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated on this!! Below is also a sample list.

0
1
0
0
0
1
0
0
1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic formula would be

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A9,0,A2:A10,1)
```

with the ranges adjusted as necessary.

If there are no empty cells in the range, this would be a bit more dynamic

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)-1),0,A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)),1)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer it is greatly appreciated! One question I have is with the second formula. What do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: And also, how would I be able to adjust the formula if I wanted to see if there were two 0 before a 1 and so forth...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer this has been extremely helpful!!